# how to check the support for x-iframe-options ALLOW-FROM?

Tags: html

Is there a way to find out if my browser supports X-IFRAME-OPTIONS and X-IFRAME-OPTIONS ALLOW-FROM in http header either client side or server side

Answer (score 0):

The following article on OWASP site contains a link to a X-Frame-Options Compatibility Test.

Have a look at

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Browser_Support